# What is <% for %> in html

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen a piece of html code like below:

```
<% for script in ['js/a.js', 'js/b.js'] %>
    <script src="/path/<$ script $>" onerror="dosomething()"></script>
<% endfor %>
```

Can anyone explain where this syntax from? In particular <% for/endfor %> tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using ASP, ASP.NET, PHP or some other programming environment, the <% %> usually tell the server to run some code and put the resulting text inside the tags. If you have a user count on the server named totalusers, let's say with a value of 10. You could write:

```
<div>Users on server is <%= totalusers %></div>
```

and the output would be

```
<div>User on server is 10</div>
```

The output of the above code will be these two script tags:

```
<script src="/path/js/a.js" onerror="dosomething()"></script>
<script src="/path/js/b.js" onerror="dosomething()"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! So these tags basically tell the server to replace the content with something else? So there must be another script to transform these tags to something else in the production code. Did I get it right?

Comment: That is right. If you serve the file as a HTML file, the tags will not be replaced by server before sending to the client browser. Only when running PHP, .Net, Java Server Pages or soemething else on the server the script inside the tages will be executed and replaced by the output.

Comment: I consider this is the answer I'm looking for. Thanks!